# Removing blanks from an array using files

Tags: c

```
void read_input(FILE* inputfile,char array[]) {
     int nscan;
     char termch;
     while(TRUE) {
        nscan = fscanf(inputfile,"%30[^\n]%c",array,&termch);
        if (nscan == EOF)
          break;
        if (nscan != 2 || termch != '\n' ){
          printf("error  \n");
        }
     }
}
```

Here is my code, could please anyone help me find out why it shows the `error` message I've added, since the value of `nscan` is 2?

Comment: I think the dollar sign before read is a typo, right?

Comment: This is not valid C. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: "When you have eliminated everything else, what remains must be the truth" (Sherlock Holmes). That leaves `|| termch != '\n'`. Did you examine the value of `termch` too? You could both values in the error message.

Comment: Describe in more detail what you are trying to do and what exactly is failing. What is `$void`? This is not legal C.

Comment: @Olaf There is a small syntax error, `$`, but other than that it is valid C.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the `$` since it is just a typo irrelevant to why the error message appears.

Comment: @self: So you agree it was not valid C. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the contents of the input file being read is.

Comment: @Olaf You're just being pedantic It was clear he copied it from a terminal emulator window.

Comment: @self: Tell that a C compiler!

Comment: You are expecting the file to contain 30 characters or less and end in newline. The error is printed when there are more than 30 characters in a line, therefore `termch` is not a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if (nscan != 2 || termch != '\n' ){
  printf("error  \n");
}
```

says:

if `nscan` is not 2 print error. If `termch` is not a newline, print error. This is because you are using the OR logic operator, `||`. This explains the behavior you are getting.

So, if you want to see more, just print the values of both variables before reaching that if statement. For sure, `termch` will be something different than a newline.

Comment: exactly, i need the nscan to be 2 since fscanf reads 2 parametrs (the string and the termch which must be '\n'). Thing is that we used this method in university for other program which nscan was 4 , and we used if (nscan !=4  || termch != '\n' )
print error. This is what im trying to do, yet i can't do it

Comment: Well George, that's a different question. I think this is an answer to your question, so I suggest you to accept it if you like it and then post a new question, but be specific, provide some input for example. Hope that helps.

Comment: c    programming    is       fun  //input
c programming is fun // output
I have done this, but my problem is that when i execute the program it gives the "error" message, while it shouldn't since it does the proper work

Comment: Please read the answer again. Do so for my upper comment too @GPwoopzi.

Comment: did it, nscan=1 and termch=u which means, it doesn't read the 'n' and the '\n' of the string

Comment: As expected... Happy debugging @GPwoopzi :) Note that you can accept the answer.

Comment: @GPwoopzi,  Please post edits to the question in the question, NOT as comments

Answer (score 0):

remembering that on Windows and DOS, that the newline sequence is actually 2 characters and not just one...

remembering that the input line could be greater than 29 characters which would cause the second parameter to NOT contain the newline...

remembering that the input line could contain some `white space` like a space or tab, then the call to fscanf() will fail.

regarding these lines:

```
if (nscan != 2 || termch != '\n' ){
      printf("error  \n");
}
```

the 'if' condition is an `or`

And `or` means if either part is true, the result is true.

So when termch != '\n'  is true, then the enclosed function body will be executed.

Suggest modify that 'if' statement to:

```
if (nscan != 2 ) 
{
    printf( "fscanf failed to read both parameters\n");
}
else if(termch != '\n' ) 
{
    printf( "fscanf failed to read the complete line\n");
}
```

such that meaningful messages are output.

---

Also, the while() loop and enclosed code leaves a bit to be desired.

suggest:

```
while(1)
{
    if( 1 != (nscan == fscanf(inputfile,"%30[^\n]\n",array) ) )       
    { 
        perror( "fscanf failed to read full line of input" );
    }
}
```

of course, if the input line is greater than 29 characters then the error message will be output and the next iteration of the loop will read the rest of the line.